# Close drawer when navigating to top StackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, rxjs, react-navigation

In most of the app from google as for example (contact, gmail, ...) whenever you click on an menu entry like "settings" / "profile" / "logout" it close the drawer and then (once animation finished) open on top the "settings" / whatever view.

I have the same need as I have a StackNavigator with [SideMenu , settings] with SideMenu as a DrawerNaVigator.

Currently I did not find any way to close "nicely" the drawer. By using the NavigationActions.back() right before the NavigationActions.navigate() it does the job but the animation overlap. By using a timeout for NavigationActions.navigation it seems to wait for the end of the drawer close but there is a too long period between drawer closed and new screen opened. This does not seems to be a valid solution anyway.

```
// close drawer
NavigationActions.navigate('DrawerClose')
// navigate and overlap drawer close
NavigationActions.navigate('settings')


// close drawer
NavigationActions.navigate('DrawerClose')
// navigate and at least wait for the end of drawer close animation
// even with 1
// Also create a latency, (drawer close, .. some ms .., navigate
setTimeout(() => {
  NavigationActions.navigate('settings')
}, 1, 2, whatever)
```

Should not we have the possibily to add action to the end of other action in order to achieve that ?
ex:

```
// close drawer
NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'DrawerClose',
  // then navigate to settings
  nextAction: NavigationActions.navigate('settings')
})
```